# Python's function update() not recognized

Tags: python, function, object, methods

```
def updateTheme(self, id, new_theme):
    theme = Theme.query.filter_by(id = id).first()
    theme.update(new_theme)
    db.session.commit()
```

Error: 'Theme' object has no attribute 'update'
This is how it should work:

```
theme = Theme(name = "osman")
new_theme = Theme(name = "miras")
theme.update(new_theme)
print(theme) # osman have to be changed to miras
```

Even if I can do like:

```
theme.name = "miras"
```

When I got to use multiple params like name, surname, phone. Also updateTheme not always providing all params (name, surname, phone) and it should update only provided params. For example:

```
person = {name: "john", surname: "smith", phone: 12345, country: "USA"}
update_person = {country: "Portugal"}
person.update(update_person) # should change only country
```

Comment: Share complete code. What's Theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update one or two fields you could use:

```
theme = Theme(name = "osman")
new_theme = Theme(name = "miras")
theme.name=new_theme.name
db.session.commit()
print(theme) # osman will change to miras
```

If you want to update more fields:

```
dict_to_update = {'name': new_theme.name}
updated_theme = Theme.query.filter_by(name="miras").update(dict_to_update)
db.session.commit()
print(theme) # osman will change to miras
```

Comment: still errors `Theme' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: I know it works this way. But Imagine I have params (name, surname, country, phone, ...) and graphql tries to update only country and phone, and name surname should remain as they were. I'm looking for short and easy way to update.

Comment: 'Theme' object is not iterable

Comment: I just used your first peace of code. It works. Thanks for help.